# CSS Is Not Being Applied to jQuery class elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I've been tasked with creating a modal for a live site as a test. I'm using the "Customer Javascript for Websites" or "CJS" extension for Chrome to try out my file.

Now, from what what I've google searched, it seems that I'm doing everything fine yet my css elements are not being applied to the div. So, check this out:

```
function modalElement() {
  var $container = $("#container");
  var $modalHtml = $("<div class='modal'><p>HELLO</p></div>");

  $(function() {
    $(".modal").css({
      height: "425px",
      width: "425px",
      border: "5px solid black"
    });
  });
  $container.append($modalHtml);
}
```

'HELLO' is showing up at the bottom of the page, so the div is being appended, but none of the css elements are being applied. I've tried putting height, width, border, within quotes, and removing the `$(function()` line. Also tried `$modalHtlm.find(".modal").css(({}))` but that doesn't work either.

Any recommendations? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your style is not working because the following function is executed before you append the html on the DOM, so $('.modal') can't find any match.

```
$(function() {
   $(".modal").css({
     height: "425px",
     width: "425px",
     border: "5px solid black"
    });
});
```

Try this instead:

```
function modalElement() {
  var $container = $("#container");
  var $modalHtml = $("<div class='modal'><p>HELLO</p></div>");

  // Append the modal to the DOM
  $container.append($modalHtml);

  // Then execute the style function
  $(function() {
    $(".modal").css({
      height: "425px",
      width: "425px",
      border: "5px solid black"
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: That's the one! I'll be using this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the styles directly in the CSS stylesheet?

```
.modal {
  height: 425px;
  width: 425px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

And inspect the modal in the browser to see if there are other selectors overwriting these styles.

Comment: One of the requirements was to keep everything to the js file

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you may not be having the element added to the page yet. Meaning you may be trying to add a class to an element that does not yet exist on the DOM. Try appending the element first before adding the style

Answer (score 0):

`$modalHtml.css()`, not `$modalHtml.find().css()`, as `find()` finds children, it isn't a child of itself so it wouldn't find what you intended.

You can also just pass a second argument to [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) telling it what attributes to use while creating an element

```
$("<div class='modal'><p>HELLO</p></div>",{
  css: {
    height: "425px",
    width: "425px",
    border: "5px solid black"
  }
});
```

Also

```
$(function() {
  $(".modal").css({
    height: "425px",
    width: "425px",
    border: "5px solid black"
  });
});
$container.append($modalHtml);
```

This didn't work as the element hadn't been added to the DOM before your code inside `$(function(){})` ran. So it didn't find the element in order to put the css onto.